# Drawing a USA flag in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Because I use a translator, English can be unnatural.

I made a code to draw the American flag, but it got stuck.
I've completed a line of stars, but I don't know how to do the same on the bottom line.

Below is the code that I wrote:

```
from turtle import *
setup(800, 500)
shape("turtle")
speed(0)

#시작점
redx = -400
redy = 250

#빨간줄 1개
def stripe():
    color("red")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        forward(800)
        right(90)
        forward(38)
        right(90)
    end_fill()

#빨간줄 7개
for i in range(7):
    penup()
    goto(redx, redy)
    pendown()
    stripe()
    redy= redy - 76

#파란 사각형
penup()
goto(-400, 250)
pendown()
color("blue")
begin_fill()
for i in range(2):
    forward(350)
    right(90)
    forward(266)
    right(90)
end_fill()

#별 1개
def star():
    color("white")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(5):
        forward(20)
        right(144)
    end_fill()



#6개짜리 별 한줄
def sixstar():
    x1=-380
    y1=230
    for i in range(6):
        penup()
        goto(x1, y1)
        pendown()
        star()
        x1 = x1 + 57
    
sixstar()
hideturtle()
```

[Run screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L73Fz.png)

I want to know how to solve it. Also please let me know if you have any better code.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `sixstar()` function to include a loop that draws multiple rows of stars, modify the range to draw as many rows as you wish.

```
def sixstar():
    x1 = - 380
    y1 = 230
    # loop for drawing multiple rows of stars
    for j in range(5):
        for i in range(6):
            penup()
            goto(x1, y1)
            pendown()
            star()
            x1 = x1 + 57
        # reset x1 to the starting position
        x1 = - 380
        # move down to the next row
        # modify this as you wish to set the distance between rows.
        y1 = y1 - 50
```